# Extra fold of docstring when using foldmethod=indent

Tags: folding

I am using `foldmethod=indent` when working on Python files. This is generally ok. However when I unfold a function, I would like the docstring to stay folded even though it is at the same indent level as the rest of the code.

For example

```
def f(x):
    """This is my docstring, lets indent a useful equation the function
    is used to calculate:
        f(x) = x.
    When opening one fold level, this docstring should stay folded.
    """

    return x
```

My unfolding would then go as follows:

1) Starting view when all folds active.

```
def f(x):
+-- 7 lines: """This is my docstring, lets indent a useful equation the function
```

2) Opening of the fold keeps the docstring folded despite being same indent level as rest of the function body.

```
def f(x):
+-- 6 lines: """This is my docstring, lets indent a useful equation the function
    return x
```

Comment: if you don't want to indent it a separate level, you would have to create a custom foldexpression and use foldexpression or marker instead of the indent based folding